# Flex Application running - The requested resource (/{Main mxml file name}.html) is not available

Tags: apache-flex

I have a problem with running flex application and I'm not sure what the source of problem is.
Here is the case:

Everytime that I clean eclipse project and restart Apcahe Tomcat server and run the application main MXML I got the following error "The requested resource (/{Main mxml file name}.html) is not available." To solve this everytime I should create a new MXML application,restart the server and then everything is fine.Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this annoying issue??? :-(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how about this but have you checked your Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and made sure that the path is right in there?

I had the same issue a while back, deleted the whole project and re-checked it out, changed the path in there, and that worked out.

Good luck!

Comment: Thx for your comment but I didn't exactly get the point. Which path should be what?